# How to get text from div which contains b tag with text

Tags: python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_text = """<div style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
                <b>Description</b><br>
                Dryer is not working. Please have someone take a look at it
            </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text,"html.parser")
work_order_no = soup.find("b",text="Description")
print(work_order_no)
add= work_order_no.next_sibling
print(add.text)
```

Required_solution : Dryer is not working. Please have someone take a look at it

Comment: Skip the `<br>` with another `.next_sibling`?

Comment: @David I didnt understand. I didnt used br and used .next_sibling not getting

Comment: `add = work_order_no.next_sibling.next_sibling` maybe?

Comment: @David Is it possible to get by parent div text

Comment: I posted my answer below. Please see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @David it resolved the issue. Is it possible to get text by parent div text means (bold text parent div text)

Comment: So you want `work_order_no.parent.text`? That will include the "Description" string.

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your issue, please consider marking it the accepted answer to help people finding this later. Thank you.

Comment: @David Thanks.. If is there any possible other method without Description string please provide.

Comment: You can first store the `work_order_no.parent`, then call `work_order_no.extract()` to remove the element, then find the text of the parent. Note that this will modify the BeautifulSoup though.

Comment: @David work_order_no.extract("b") like this.. is not working

Comment: Nope, just `work_order_no.extract()` with no arguments

Comment: @David Can you help me with this parent_work_no = work_order_no.parent,
extract_bold_text = work_order_no.extract().. This after that what should do

Comment: `print(parent_work_no.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML code, `work_order_no.next_sibling` refers to the element that comes after `<b>Description</b>`, and that is `<br>`. You need to find the next element after that. To do this, try:

```py
add= work_order_no.next_sibling.next_sibling
print(add.text)
```

Comment: Glad to help you! @BenDavid

Comment: You might also want to strip whitespace from `add.text`